# What is the difference between <> and != operators in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, operators

If I use a simple table such as :

```
create table test ( a int );
insert into test values ( 1 ) , ( 2 ) , ( 2 ) , ( 3 );
select * from test where a <> 2;
select * from test where a != 2;
```

Both give me :

```
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    3 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So what is the difference between `<>` and `!=` mysql operators ?

Comment: I can't find any documentation explicitly saying so, but they are synonymous.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

They are both exactly the same. See the documentation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

Comment: Thank you, strange notation. Just seen that on a coworker code and just got stuck.

Comment: Yeah, while I use C-based languages mainly I tend to use `<>` even though `!=` feels more natural to me. `<>` just seems right for any SQL representation.

Answer (score 34):

`<>` should be preferred, all things being equal, since it accords with the sql standard and is technically more portable...

`!=` is non-standard, but most db's implement it.

sql:2008 grammar:

```
<not equals operator> ::=
  <>
```

Comment: why is it technically more portable?

Comment: @Dennis I guess because it is sql standard.

Comment: @Dennis it should be more compatible to use `<>` and easily to transplant the query in different RDBMS. so it's considering portable?

Answer (score 7):

No difference. `<>` is sql standard, `!=` non-standard.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing.  Simply two different ways of writing the same thing