# Show all records except a few in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to ask how to display all records except for TRX0613-021
Here's is my table

[image: table]

So I need to know how to do that for my assignment.

"Display data in the transaction details table whose transaction ID is not TRX0613-021"

Comment: `SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE id_transaksi <> 'TRX0613-021'`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? And how is this related to PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the SQL `<>` ("not equal to") [operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_operators.asp), *i.e.*

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE id_transaksi <> 'TRX0613-021'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT ID_TRANSAKSI,ID_BARANG,JML
    FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE ID_TRANSAKSI<>'TRX0613-021';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of the following :

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE id_transaksi <> 'TRX0613-021'
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE id_transaksi != 'TRX0613-021'
```

The queries return all the data in table except the row where `id_transaksi` is `TRX0613-021`

Please read more about using `!=` and `<>` on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159569/what-is-the-difference-between-and-operators-in-mysql)